# How to solve VidoePlayer PlatformException in flutter

Tags: flutter, preload, video-player, codexl, podplayer

I use [preload_page_view](https://pub.dev/packages/preload_page_view) and [pod_player](https://pub.dev/packages/pod_player)  to show youtube shorts in my app. After 30-40 pages i get same exception : PlatformException (PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.42C01E, -1, null, [360, 640, 25.0], [-1, -1]), format_supported=YES, null, null)). How can I solve this or can you suggest another way to show youtube shorts in my app smoothly (I mean preloading shorts)?

I add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to AndroidManifest.xml but I get same issue.